# Java, how o get the video length in milliseconds

Tags: java, video, duration, milliseconds

I've tried xuggler and IMBPlayerForMpeg4, and both aren't working for some reason, so please if you have a new method tell me, or else please re explain either of those two...

IBMPlayer thorws an IOException everytime

Xuggler crashes for a reason i cannot determine, but it originates from the `IContainer container = IContainer.make();`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible that your video could be corrupt??